# CSS3 filter:opacity(X) with fallback to opacity:X, same for filter:drop-shadow() to box-shadow

Tags: css, opacity, box-shadow, css-filters

I would like to start using the CSS3 filter:opacity() and filter:drop-shadow() properties that are currently under development, as I read that they are hardware accelerated in some browsers on some machines. But at this early point I definitely need a fallback to normal CSS properties like opacity and box-shadow.

Problem is, that the normal CSS fallback strategy of placing new after old fails. Normally new (if supported) would overwrite old. But in this case new and old are completely different properties that will combine! The CSS declaration...

```
.half-transparent{
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0.5);
    filter: opacity(0.5);
}
```

...will result in a total opacity of 25% instead of 50%.

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/uq4ybvk8/

Is there any way (preferably CSS only) to create a fallback from the new filter properties to well established CSS properties?

Comment: There's no need to use both `opacity` and `filter:opacity` at the same time....`opacity` isn't going anywhere. `filter:opacity` is *just another option* and they aren't **exactly** interchangeable. I suspect you would need to use feature detection like [**Modernizr**](https://modernizr.com/) if this is really an issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Please read my text. I have clearly stated that I want to use filter:opacity because of performance advantages over opacity (hardware acceleration). I have a real use case where opacities and box-shadows imposed over high-res images really create performance issues on Android Chrome browsers (which might benefit from hardware acceleration).

Comment: Then you'd need to use feature detection as mentioned.

Comment: I have added a "preferably CSS only" to my question. I was hoping that there is a pure CSS way.

Comment: Then...No there really isn't. If they are both supported they will both be used as they aren't the same property even though they have virtually the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for `filter` (with and without prefix) should overlap pretty nicely with support for the Conditional Rules module (`@supports`), with the exception of older versions of Safari/iOS (before Safari 9). If you treat it as an enhancement (i.e. with a fallback to regular `opacity` for other browsers), that shouldn't be a big issue. Try something like this, perhaps?

```
.half-transparent {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
@supports ((filter: opacity(0.5)) or (-webkit-filter: opacity(0.5))) {
  .half-opacity {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0.5);
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting option that I was not aware of.
Unfortunately it is not working for a large number of older Safari versions, but I will still mark it as accepted answer.